# Checking string format with regex in PHP

Tags: php, regex

I have been trying to use preg_match with `"/^[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+$/"` trying to make sure that the string given only contained the characters there and nothing else, but it seems to not be counting the $ properly so that it matches all the way to the end of the line, but it does require the match at the start of the string using ^.

If I use `{3,}` instead of `+`: `"/^[a-zA-Z0-9_-]{3,}$/"` which is how I had it at first, I could write 3 letters/numbers, - or _ and then any character other than those and it would count it as a match.

code:

```
  if(preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+$/", $value, $arr) && strlen($value) > 3)
  {
   echo $good .' Ok';
  }
  else
  {
   echo $bad .' Invalid username. (letters & numbers only)';
  }
```

using things like the following as $value, it tells me it is ok when it should be coming up as invalid username because of the space or & characters.

> word word
>
> word&word

And it turns out it was because the values were being sent to the page through $_GET and $value of something such as "word&word" came up as "word" instead... is there a way to fix that?

Comment: This should work, see http://rubular.com/r/NCA8fghoxo

Comment: Can you give some examples, which strings should match and which don't work? (And also your PHP code, maybe you are doing something wrong, the regex looks good to me).

Comment: So you can have ONLY letters and numbers

Comment: What do you mean it fails with 'word word' and 'word & word'? It works just fine. See http://ideone.com/eJc2d

Comment: Please clarify on how it doesn't works, it works fine to me...

Answer (score 2):

> And it turns out it was because the values were being sent to the page through $_GET and $value of something such as "word&word" came up as "word" instead... is there a way to fix that?

I'm throwing a wild guess here that your PHP page that you call from browser as http://yoursite/page.php?something=word&word is reading `$_GET['something']` to be `word` instead of your expected `word&word`.

Well, this is because literal ampersand symbol is treated as $_GET parameters delimiter and any ampersand symbol that you want to include in a parameter value must be url-encoded as `%26`, as in http://yoursite/page.php?something=word%26word . In PHP, you can use function `urlencode()` to encode your string values:

```
$url = 'http://yoursite/page.php?something=' . urlencode('word&word');
```

Comment: The footnote to this is the `$_GET` and `$_POST` are automatically urldecoded, so there's no need to `urldecode()` manually on the other side.

Answer (score 0):

> And it turns out it was because the
>   values were being sent to the page
>   through $_GET and $value of something
>   such as "word&word" came up as "word"
>   instead... is there a way to fix that?

You'll need to encode the ampersand in the URL:

[url]/script.php?string=word&word

becomes

[url]/script.php?string=word&amp;word

Try using [urlencode](http://www.php.net/urlencode) if the link's being generated by PHP.

**Edit** Or try using _POST instead.